# C# DataGridView not showing Data (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to make a simple binding from SQL server to a DataGridView in C# but this code is not working (My programming skills are little rusty)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public IQueryable<boklet2> qry;
        public AnalysisUpgradeEntities Ana = new AnalysisUpgradeEntities();

        public class boklet2
        {
            public int _ID;
            public int? _ItemSpecs;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            qry = from an in Ana.analysis_pipes
                  select new boklet2
                  {
                      _ID = an.ID,
                      _ItemSpecs = an.itemSpecs
                  };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = qry.ToList();
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = qry;
        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing a library I should add with the word Using I also tried adding the `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True` but still no data is shown

Comment: What does `qry` variable contains after running the query?

Comment: have you check that returned list has elements???

Comment: My C# is rusty, but don't you need a Databind some place?

Comment: @NiranjanKala I cheched and it contains the 10 elements I added in the SQL server table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
public class boklet2
{
    public int _ID;
    public int? _ItemSpecs;
}
```

to this

```
public class boklet2
{
    public int _ID { get; set; }
    public int? _ItemSpecs { get; set; }
}
```

and let me know

Explanation provided by @AdamVincent, thank you!

> Fields are ordinary member variables or member instances of a class. Properties are an abstraction to get and set their values. Properties are also called accessors because they offer a way to change and retrieve a field if you expose a field in the class as private. A field is public int _ID;, and the fix was to add the accessors by using the auto property syntax public int _ID { get; set; }

Comment: `Still, no data is shown in the DataGridView. I am confused what could possibly be wrong ?!!` Its working now

Comment: Sorry my fault its working now, but what was the problem might I ask ?

Comment: @Tima, I do not know the official answer, but I'll go on a limp and say that _I assume the DataGridView initializer does not know how to properly initialize the grid when the fields it needs to display don't have a setter because it's unable to create the initial instance of the field_ <- It's not exactly how I have it worded in my head but that's how it came out...

Comment: Fields are ordinary member variables or member instances of a class. Properties are an abstraction to get and set their values. Properties are also called accessors because they offer a way to change and retrieve a field if you expose a field in the class as private.  A field is `public int _ID;`, and the fix was to add the accessors by using the auto property syntax `public int _ID { get; set; }`

Comment: please update this code only response with some more information.